# SR-IOV on IBM x3690

Tags: ibm

Is IBM x3690 has SR-IOV capability?
If so - how to configure the BIOS to support it?

I used Google to search for an answer and reached this link:
ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/eserver/benchmarks/wp_SR-IOV_Red_Hat_111810.pdf

As I understand it supports SR-IOV but I couldn't find in in BIOS Settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Support for SR-IOV is dependent on three things; systemboard chipset support, PCIe adapter support and OS support. IBM's eX5 chipset supports the protocol so if you pick an adapter and OS that support it too then you're good.

Comment: Further reading: http://blog.scottlowe.org/2009/12/02/what-is-sr-iov/